# Spring Security SAML, ADFS, Okta SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, adfs, okta

I need to implement single sign on for my Java Spring Boot Applications. The components I have available are Okta and ADFS. I have browsed through various spring security documentations as well as stack overflow posts.  Most of them are 5-6 years old.  Could anyone give me some pointers or any sample implementations in regard to Spring Security 5?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fastest way to get started with Spring Boot and Okta. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/11/24/spring-boot-okta.

This uses the [Okta Spring Boot starter](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot), which is a thin wrapper around Spring Security's OAuth / OIDC support.